# Git. Как сбросить/удалить сохраненный пароль?

Tags: windows, git, windows-7, bitbucket

У меня есть у/з на BitBucket. Пришлось сменить на ней пароль, теперь при попытке выполнить

```
git fetch
```

я вижу ошибку:

> fatal: Authentication failed for 'Адрес'

Насколько я понял, гит сохранил мой пароль и теперь пытается его использовать.
Как мне сбросить этот пароль?

Можно конечно удалить и заново клонировать  репозитарий, но хочется найти способ проще.

Comment: "Можно конечно удалить и заново клонировать репозитарий" во-первых, это может и не помочь, если используется хранилище учётных данных Windows; во-вторых, можно склонировать ещё один, не удаляя первый, и проверить.

Comment: Клонирование работает. К сожалению, политика ИБ в нашей компании заставляет нас менять пароли каждые 2 недели. Каждый раз тащить по несколько ГГБ не очень интересно, вот я и ищу способ просто сбрасывать пароль

Comment: Хм. Посмотрите в файл `.git/config` внутри репозитория, может, там есть улики.

Comment: git config --global --unset user.password , но оно вроде сотрет все пароли

Comment: Можно воспользоваться каким нибудь приложением для гита, типа SourceTree. Там в настройках можно редактировать пароль

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалить пароль:

```
git config --unset user.password
```

Похоже, в некоторых случаях пароль сохраняется глобально, и можно использовать

```
git config --global --unset user.password
```

Answer (score 2):

Мне --unset user.password не помогло, однако помогло сменить https:// на http://  в адресе репозитория в mnage remotes через GITExtensions. После такой манипуляции он логин и пароль переспросил... Не знаю, поможет ли обратная смена следующий раз..

UPD: адреса гита с учётками замечены в списке, доступном в Windows 10 вот тут: «Панель управления» / «Учетные записи пользователей и Семейная безопасность» / «Диспетчер учетных данных» / «Учётные данные Windows»  / «Общие учётные данные».